# Relatively simple React app has a component re-rendering 7 times on page load

Tags: reactjs

My React app is currently fairly simple in terms of structure, though the logic in the components is getting more intense. The structure is basically `Index` which has a `Header` component and, if the user is logged in, will load the `Home` component, which has components `X`, `Y`, and `Z` on it, corresponding to left sidebar, main area, and right sidebar.

As I'm working on the right sidebar, I have some `console.log()` statements to help out. I'm now noticing that the right sidebar `Z` component appears to render 7 times for a given fresh page load, based on how frequently I see my logging. This component has the rough following code:

- Declaring various states for the component using `React.useState([default value])`
- Checks the Redux store to fetch the currently authed user of my app (`authedUser`)
- A `React.useEffect()` that checks if there is an authed user and if so, sets a couple component states. This `useEffect` triggers off of `, [authedUser]);` - I suspect this may be a cause of the rerendering?
- Some click event handlers, including a more complex one that makes Google API calls when a certain button is clicked, using

The Redux store value for `authedUser` is used in `Index`, `Header`, and `Z`. The `dispatch` call that can change this store value only happens within functions relating to the user logging in.

Questions:

1. Am I right in being concerned that this component is re-rendering so much?
2. Any ideas on what might be causing it?
3. Are there any tools I can use to answer the "when/why is this re-rendering?" question?

Comment: In React whenever you have a parent-child relationship, any change in the parent will re-render the child, even if it's not a child-related data change, better read more about memo and callback.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Answer (score 0):

You have a home component and three children's components on it. You may have a state variable in your home component and pass these state variables as props on to child components. Your home components re-render each time when each state variable changes its state, resulting in child components having to be re-rendered. So as to make the child component re-render only when its related state variable changes its state, you need to use the react memo and the useCallback hook.